# Auth0 - Insufficient Scope Error in Express.js using 'express-oauth2-jwt-bearer' Package

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, auth0

I was going to create a private-scoped endpoint on my Express.js backend API to check some custom permissions. I'm using RBAC (Role-Based Access Control) in auth0 with the 'express-oauth2-jwt-bearer' (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-oauth2-jwt-bearer) package. I constantly get an Insufficient Scope Error when I try to access that endpoint.

Express Code,

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { auth, requiredScopes } = require('express-oauth2-jwt-bearer');

const checkJwt = auth();

const requiredScopes = requiredScopes("getAll:student", { customScopeKey: "permissions" });

app.get(
  "/student/getAll",
  checkJwt,
  requiredScopes,
  res.json({
      message: 'Here is the all Student detail list'
  });
);
```

Decoded JSON web token details,
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtZfU.jpg

```
{
  "iss": "https://*************.us.auth0.com/",
  "sub": "auth0|******************",
  "aud": [
    "http://*************",
    "https://*************.us.auth0.com/userinfo"
  ],
  "iat": 1657083984,
  "exp": 1657170384,
  "azp": "***********************",
  "scope": "openid profile email",
  "permissions": [
    "delete:student",
    "getAll:student",
    "search:student",
    "update:student"
  ]
}
```

But if I use `const requiredScopes = requiredScopes("openid profile email", { customScopeKey: "permissions" });` instead of `const requiredScopes = requiredScopes("getAll:student", { customScopeKey: "permissions" });` it works. I think the problem is permissions are not check against custom scope key but with default scope key. Anyone can help to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "getAll:student" into the token scope

"scope": "openid profile email getAll:student"

Comment: how can i add it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue - it seems that `requiredScopes` is broken. What I did instead was use `claimCheck` from the same library:

```js
const checkClaims = claimCheck(claims => {
  return claims.permissions.includes('your:permission')
});
```